# How to assign Integers, Booleans and Date objects to a key value pair in android Sqlite database

Tags: java, android, oop, android-sqlite, android-database

How to design key-value store in android Sqlite database to store and retrieve (in a type-safe manner) Integers, Booleans and Date objects?
what should be the design of the database? And how I can use the solution to handle more types in the future?